# Epiphany: Print selection

Tags: epiphany

Does anyone know if it's possible to print only the selected part of a web page to a PDF in Epiphany? I've tried searching for a solution, but couldn't find anything, though I could be searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to copy paste some text, do you want to mantain the page structure?

Comment: I'm wanting to select part of a webpage and print that to a PDF.

Comment: The only thing you can do is open the print dialog and select a custom scale. Then choose what pages you want to print (1,2,3...) . That way you will only print to pdf an specific part of the website. There's no solution that I know of in any web browser. Maybe consider screenshoting the website and cropping the image afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, I'm afraid.

Comment: That is the conclusion I've come to unfortunately. It would be a nice feature.